# tabulate function does not work with multiple candidate elimination and multiple preferences

Tags: c, cs50

I have a C file that I am working on that is based on the run off system. however, I am running into some issues.

My tabulate function is able to tabulate the correct number of votes per candidate only when one candidate is eliminated per round, but unable to tabulate the correct votes per candidate when multiple people are eliminated or handle multiple preferences.

Here is my code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid (done and checked)
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates (done)
void tabulate(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < voter_count; j++)
        {
            if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
            {
                if (preferences[j][0] == i)
                {
                    candidates[i].votes++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one (done)
bool print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        float percent = ((float) candidates[i].votes / (float) voter_count);
        if (percent > 0.5 && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has (done)
int find_min(void)
{
    // TODO
    int min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            min = candidates[i].votes;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes < min && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            min = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    return min;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise (done)
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    // TODO
    int count_votes = 0;
    int count_false = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            count_false++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            count_votes = count_votes + candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    double average = (double) count_votes / (double) count_false;


    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == average && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place (done)
void eliminate(int min)
{
    // TODO
    int candidate_index;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min)
        {
            candidate_index = i;
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        if(preferences[i][0] == candidate_index)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                preferences[i][j-1] = preferences[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return;
}
```

The code should be able to handle multiple candidate elimination and multiple preferences as in eliminate(), I have coded it such that the first preference, preferences[voter_count][0] is always the most updated, and there would never have be votes of eliminated candidates as first preference. However, when i used the cs50 checker to check my work, it claims that my function cannot handle multiple eliminations and cannot handle multiple preferences.

After thinking and trying other methods, I came up with a loop in tabulate() to count the votes so that if the voter's first preference is eliminated, there would be another loop to find the voter's next candidate preference who was not eliminated. cs50 check threw back the same errors as it did previously, now adding that I cannot calculate the correct number of votes per person when only one person is eliminated.

The code is as such:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid (done and checked)
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates (done)
void tabulate(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < voter_count; j++)
        {
            if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
            {
                if (preferences[j][0] == i)
                {
                    candidates[i].votes++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 1; k < candidate_count; k++)
                {
                    int e = preferences[j][k];
                    if (!candidates[e].eliminated)
                    {
                        candidates[e].votes++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one (done)
bool print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        float percent = ((float) candidates[i].votes / (float) voter_count);
        if (percent > 0.5 && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has (done)
int find_min(void)
{
    // TODO
    int min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            min = candidates[i].votes;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes < min && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            min = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    return min;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise (done)
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    // TODO
    int count_votes = 0;
    int count_false = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            count_false++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            count_votes = count_votes + candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    double average = (double) count_votes / (double) count_false;


    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == average && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place (done)
void eliminate(int min)
{
    // TODO
    int candidate_index;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min)
        {
            candidate_index = i;
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I have tested the code myself and still could not figure out why the amended code could not handle a single elimination, especially since I tested both codes with a simple use case whereas one candidate was eliminated, and it gave back the intended response.

Can someone see if I am doing something wrong, and give me pointer on how to get about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem...

I fix this by changing my tabulate function.

In my case, I forgot to concatenate the candidate variable inside the loop.
In the new solution, I generate a nested for. It works to me:

```
void tabulate(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            int id = preferences[i][j];
            if (!candidates[id].eliminated)
            {
                candidates[id].votes++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```